# British expatriate travelling to U.K. with only a few months left on passport

Tags: uk, passports

I'm travelling to the U.K. from the States as a U.S. permanent resident in mid-July. I still have my British passport, but it expires in mid-October.

For the life of me I can't find any expiry eligibility requirements for this situation, so I was hoping someone here may be in the know.

Comment: There should be no problem entering the UK using your UK passport, even if it expires the next day. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure because the US permanent resident stuff didn't seem to be relevant. I'll make a proper answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a valid UK passport, UK immigration control will let you into the country even if your passport expires the next day.

If you're intending to return to the US before your passport expires, you will also want to ensure that your passport is still valid for at least the minimum time required by the US officials at the time you re-enter (I'm not sure what that is for permanent residents).

Comment: Could you enter on an already expired passport?

Comment: Thanks again, Greg. Good spot RE: return immigration too.

Comment: @Grzenio: I don't know for sure. Probably. But I would have a backup plan in that case.

Comment: U.S. permanent residents technically don't need a passport to enter the U.S. But the airline may not fly you if your passport is expired.